# how to load the pdf file inside iframe in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display Pdf file inside iframe control.I have added my code like this below.

```
in asp page,

<iframe width=500 height=500 runat="server" id="myPDF" src="pdf_003.pdf"></iframe>

in page_load

myPDF.Attributes.Add("src", "pdf_003.pdf");
```

When i run the project, then the pdf file is not visible inside the iframe.Instead of this, it shown the save as dialog box for save to disk or open in pdf reader.

it is correctly shown in internet explorer but not any other browser...

How do i view the pdf file inside iframe control in all other browser?

Please Guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change Acrobat Reader's settings so it will display PDF files on the browser itself.

See [this](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/331/331025.html) Adobe KB article